# Does not move the rectangle

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a button on the form. By pressing the button the rectangle must move. But nothing happens, why?
To me important that the button is async because I want to call in the future asynchronous methods.

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="849,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="45" Width="196" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

</Grid>
```

C#:

```
private double step = 5;

private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            MoveRect();
            Sleep(100);
        }
    }

private void MoveRect()
    {
        rect.Margin = new Thickness(rect.Margin.Left + step, rect.Margin.Top + step, rect.Margin.Right - step, rect.Margin.Bottom - step);
    }

static void Sleep(int ms)
    {
        new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(ms);
    }
```

Comment: What technology is that? wpf/silverlight ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Why are you not using animation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing Windows Store App then your button click event will be like this.

```
using Windows.UI.Core;

private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => MoveRect());
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this piece of code raises quite a few questions. The most important one is @Xyroid's one: Why are you not using animation?  WPF/Silverlight already have built-in support for doing such things.

Hovewer, considering you're completely sure what you're doing and just want to get the code you've submitted working I can propose the following quick-fix:

```
while (true)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(MoveRect));
    Sleep(100);
}
```

It works on my PC (r). But let me know if it helps you.